# Why won't XCode allow me to drag and drop an object onto a view?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

When working with my view under view controller, why can I not drag and drop an object from the Object Library onto my view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XCode will not allow you to drag and drop if the view of your work space is zoomed out. Zoom back in and it should let you drag and drop in objects from the library.